# Trouble changing width size using user input

Tags: javascript, html, css

So i'm learning Web Development and i'm having issue taking a users input via forms and then setting the width of a container to that input.

First i take the user input in html.

```
<form class="changesize" action="#">
    Width: <input type="text" name="width" id="txt_width">
   <input type="button" name="submit" value="Change Container Size" 
   onclick="containersize();">
</form>
```

The following HTML is the container i wish to resize along with the text within it.

    `<div id="container">`

     `<p>Lorem ipsum dolor s...</p>`

    `</div>`

Now this is the JS which should take this input and then change the container width.

```
function containersize(){
  var containerwidth = document.getElementById('txt_width');
  var formatwidth = containerwidth.text + ".px";
  var container = document.getElementById('container');
  container.style.width = formatwidth;
}
```

Please help!

Thanks!

Comment: just change  var formatwidth = containerwidth.text + ".px";    to    var formatwidth = containerwidth.value + ".px"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a typo error in your concatenation (change"`.px`" with "`px`") plus change `text` to `value` to get the value of the input. see the snippet

```js
function containersize(){
  var containerwidth = document.getElementById('txt_width');
  var formatwidth = containerwidth.value + "px";
  console.log(formatwidth);
  var container = document.getElementById('container');
  container.style.width = formatwidth;
}
```

```html
<form class="changesize" action="#">
    Width: <input type="text" name="width" id="txt_width">
   <input type="button" name="submit" value="Change Container Size" 
   onclick="containersize();">
</form>

The following HTML is the container i wish to resize along with the text within it.
<div id="container">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor s...</p>
</div>

Now this is the JS which should take this input and then change the container width.
```